# Image text not read properly by tesseract OCR in android

Tags: android

My application which has a tesseract ocr v3.02 is running properly by displaying images but the text is not displaying properly in my edittext , some unwanted characters are also showing up or some characters are getting replaced by some different characters, please need some help from all the experienced guys out there who have already implemented such applications.

I also want to know whether the tesseract ocr only reads texts which has a plain white background or it also reads texts properly like the image output which i have posted.

Also when i take pictures from my inbuilt camera it takes hell lot of time to display the output and after that also the text is not displayed properly.
I just want my app to read the texts which are present only in my image

Posting here are the 2 screenshots of my output , please have a look at it

[image]

[image]

Also posting my code here :

```
ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(picturePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        int rotate = 0;

        switch (exifOrientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        }

        if (rotate != 0) {

            // Setting pre rotate
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.preRotate(rotate);

            // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight,
                    mtx, false);
        }
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);
        baseApi.setPageSegMode(PageSegMode.PSM_AUTO_OSD);
        baseApi.setPageSegMode(PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_LINE);
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(LanguageFilePath, "eng");
        String whiteList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-";
        String blackList = "@#$%*()+~`/&";
        baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, whiteList);
        baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, blackList);
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll(blackList, " ");
        baseApi.end();

        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng")) {
            recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ");
        }
```

Please any suggestions are welcomed , any changes i have to make please guide me. 
Thanking You.

Comment: OCR software is always subject to inaccuracies. You may add some more intelligence by using a custom **vocabulary of transformations**, So, i.e.: `INEVER` becomes `NEVER`, `WOUI D` becomes `WOULD`, and so on.

Comment: sir yes thats the problem i am facing right now , could you provide me with some link which shows how to create our own custom vocabulary ?

Comment: You could simply use a database table for that.

Comment: `I also want to know whether the tesseract ocr only reads texts which has a plain white background`. Well you can answer that yourself now. It does not need that. But of course it will do at best if characters can be distinguished good from background.

Comment: @greenapps sir if possible for you can you tell me how to tell tesseract not to read italicc font ? have you ever worked with tesseract ocr before?

Comment: No. Never saw it before. Is it expensive?